# Javascript KENDOUI GRID formatting string and float

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a grid with few columns. One of the column value is returned as string from service. This actually represents a float value. It could be any float value like 100.123. It could also be empty string ''. I need to allow sorting on this column also. What is the right way to format this column so that formatting will be correct and also the column will be sorted properly.
For example currently I have code as

```
                    {
                        field: 'value',
                        title: 'value(Cumulative)',
                        width: '120px',
                        template: '#= kendo.parseFloat(value) #'
                    },
```

When I use this code when I have empty string it gets formatted as NaN. How do I prevent this?
Also how do I ensure that the sorting also works.

Comment: To whoever down-voted this question, it is meaningless if you don't state what's wrong with it. You're just hurting his reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If i would do it, i prefer doing it on the datasource parse function. First i will create a parse function like :

```
parse: function(response) {
  var products = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(response[i].price) && response[i].price.toString().indexOf('.') != -1){
        response[i].parsedPrice = parseFloat(response[i].price);
    }else{
          response[i].parsedPrice = parseFloat(0);
    }
    products.push(response[i]);
  }

  return products;
}
```

add my logic there, if i do not want to change of the original field i will simply create another field for display purpose. Maybe you could check [this dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AxahU) for working example.